# How to use same name tag to display innerhtml according to click?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, innerhtml

html

```
<div name="hhh" class="col-sm-7  new" align="left" >

</div>
```

javascript

```
yes.onclick =function()
{
var all = document.getElementsByName("hhh");
    for(var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) 
        {
            all[i].innerHTML="You have clicked Yes.";

        }
 }


no.onclick =function()
{
var all = document.getElementsByName("hhh");
    for(var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) 
        {
            all[i].innerHTML="You have clicked No.";

        }
 }
```

Here in html two buttons are there yes and no.If the user clicks yes,yes.onclick() will execute and if user clicks no,no.onclick() will execute.
In the same division hhh, i have to display the message according to click. But if i write the above code,the message is displayed even before the click.
It is considering hhh as only one name. how can i edit the code, so that it will display message according to the click? Right now it is over writing the existing message.I dont want to over write.I want to display the previous message also.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you're asking. And what are 'yes' and 'no' ?

Comment: Yes and no are two buttons and these js functions are for clicking yes and no buttons

Comment: Guess you have one too many set of () bracets somewhere that already trigger the code. Without the HTML fo the buttons, can't say what's wrong though. When assigning events, depending on the syntax used, the event will already be run.

Comment: There is no `name` attribute for div elements in HTML. Start by [writing valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4c7xofa9/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div name="hhhYest" class="col-sm-7" onClick="clickEvent('yes')"  new" align="left" >
</div>
 <div name="hhhNo" class="col-sm-7" onClick="clickEvent('no')"  new" align="left" ></div>
```

```
function clickEvent(yesOrNo)
{
//your logic here yesOrNo

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

u should use getElementsByTagName() or better u should use getElementById if you have only one div.

Where do you assign name "yes" and "no" to a js var? maybe the problem is that.
if there are no reason to assign function dinamically by code you can also define only one function

```
function myError(e){
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("hhh");
        for(var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) 
        {
            all[i].innerHTML="You have clicked " + e.value;

        }
}
```

then assign function to ur button

```
<input type="button" value="yes/no" onClick="myError(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle click events in javascript. It seems like you are trying to design a button UI. You should not have to parse an array of elements, chose a better selector. Also there is no name attribute for **div** elements in HTML, your **all** array is null.

One way to do it is shown below.

https://jsfiddle.net/699ddkvk/

```
<div id="hi" style="background-color: red; width:50px; height:50px;" align="left" ></div>
<br>
<div id="ho" style="background-color: blue; width:50px; height:50px;" align="left" ></div>

red = document.getElementById("hi");
blue = document.getElementById("ho");

red.onclick=function(){
   red.innerHTML="YES";
};

blue.onclick=function(){
    blue.innerHTML="YES";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> all[i].innerHTML = ...
> ```

```
all[i].innerHTML += "\n" + ...
```

And don't fiorget to set

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

in css.